# Spring Resource server syncing roles with database

Tags: spring, spring-security

We have a spring boot application used as a resource server. Our client would like to restrain access to a certain list of users contained in a database.

Right now, anyone can access the application if they login to the issuer (which is public). I would like to link a role to each user, especially the one present in my database.

I've been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100420/spring-oauth2-resource-server-load-synchronized-user-from-database) solution, but I would like to only call the database the first time.

The JWT converter :

```
@Override
public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NotNull final Jwt jwt) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (Objects.isNull(auth)){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        if(Objects.nonNull(userController)){
            CollectionModel<User> userList = /* Getting info from DB here */
            if(!userList.getContent().isEmpty()){
                User user = userList.getContent().iterator().next();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRole().name().toUpperCase()));
            }
        } else {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CONSULT"));
        }
        AbstractAuthenticationToken newAuth = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
        return newAuth;
    }
    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, auth.getAuthorities());
}
```

Security config

```
http.authorizeRequests( authori -> authori.antMatchers( "URL_1", "URL_2" )
                .authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtConverter())
                )
        );
```

The problem is that every time a request is made, `getAuthentication()` returns null, as if no authentication was found.
I'm fairly new to Spring, so I might not understand everything yet, especially for the security part.

Did anyone encounter this and if so, how did you get through ?

Thanks !